# How can I view a component's filename and line number in React Native?

Tags: react-native, inspector

After upgrading my application from RN 0.46 to 0.71, I can't see the box in the Element Inspector that mentions the filename and line number of the component.

I've tried almost all of the debugging tools (Flipper, React DevTools, React Native Debugger) but I haven't managed to find a way to see the filename and line number of any component. I also tried to start a new template RN app using `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject` but to no effect. I have also tried creating an app in previous RN versions (0.65, 0.68) but nothing works. It was one of the handiest features of React Native that helped a lot during development. Can anybody help me get it back?

Comment: Are you perhaps using any log monitoring tools like sentry.io?

Comment: No, I haven't used any log monitoring tools.

Comment: Any update here? 
still haven't found a solution to this problem